# How precise is python's agglomerative clustering algorithm?

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, precision, hierarchical-clustering

Apologies if a question like this is inappropriate for this platform but I can't find any information on this anywhere. I'm using sklearn to do a cluster analysis on some points; this is the relevant portion of my code:

```
    clustering = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=None, affinity='euclidean',
                                 distance_threshold=d, linkage='single').fit(i)
    number = clustering.n_clusters_
```

I would like to know the precision to which I can define 'd' which in this case is the distance threshold above which clusters won't be merged. For example, if I set d = 0.000002, would it use this value or would it be rounded to zero? How many decimal places can I use basically.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scikit-learn's `AgglomerativeClustering` class stores the `distance_threshold` value as a `float` type, which on most Python systems means double precision, that is 64 bit. The decimal number you enter is converted to a base-2 exponential number under the hood and rounded accordingly if necessary to fit into the 64 bit storage slot. 1 bit is reserved for the sign, 11 bits for the exponent, and 52 bits for the significant digits.

Note that when you have a number such as `0.000002`, starting with many zeros and having only one significant digit, the factor determining the smallest possible value is the number of bits for the exponent. So the question is, how small a number can be represented with 11 bits storage for the exponent?
Let's see:

```py
2 ** -(2 ** 11)
```

Out: `0.0`

```py
2 ** -(2 ** 10)
```

Out: `5.562684646268003e-309`

So if you enter your `d` value as a decimal number, without using exponential notation, you would have to type at least 309 zeros for that limit to kick in. Thus the value will practically never be rounded to zero, but there will be a small rounding error unless your decimal number happens to have a simple base-2 representation.